# Only allow access to a table via a function, not directly via queries

Tags: postgresql, permissions, role, acl

I have a table `t` and some functions which access `t`. For example:

```
create function list_t() returns setof t as $$
    select * from t;
$$ language sql stable;
```

Is it possible to define role permissions to only allow the execution of `list_t()`, while not allowing plain `SELECT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` and `INSERT` queries on `t`?

I tried the following:

```
grant execute on all functions in schema public to my_user;
revoke all on t from my_user;
```

While this indeed disallows `SELECT * FROM t`, it also disallows `SELECT list_t()`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to create the function as a user that has (select) access to the underlying table. Then define the function with the option `security defined` which means when the function is called, it operates with the privileges of the function *owner*, not the caller:

```
create function list_t() returns setof t 
  security definer
as $$
    select * from t;
$$ language sql stable;
```

---

Another way of doing this is to create a view, then grant SELECT privileges to the view (not the table):

```
create view v_t
as
select *
from t;

grant select on v_t to my_user;
```

---

Note that a set returning function should be used in the `FROM` clause like a table:

```
select *
from list_t();
```

Comment: Adding 'security definer' works, interesting concept. Just wondering, what is wrong with `select list_t()`?

Comment: @Katrin: The expressions in the select list should be scalar values (single values), not a set of rows. Would you think that `select some_table` makes sense?

Comment: I can see that in case of plain columns and regular tables, but not in the context of functions. Isn't that the same as `select unnest('{1,2,3}'::int[])`, which gives the same output as `select * from unnest('{1,2,3}'::int[])`?

Comment: That is not recommended either

Comment: Oh really, I did not really know that. I appreciate it that you brought it up!

Answer (score 0):

The issue brought up here is easily resolved by using `SECURITY DEFINER`. However, it's worth noting that code that runs in procedures and functions marked as `SECURITY DEFINER` cannot utilize transaction support (such as `COMMIT` or `ROLLBACK`).